rdflib not parsing rdf file
im trying to open an rdf file using rdflib in python but it is not working here are my codes:
import rdflib

g = rdflib.Graph

g.parse("C:\Users\UserName\Documents\jazzmusic.rdf")

and got the error
PS C:\Users\UserName\Documents> & C:/Users/UserName/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/python.exe c:/Users/UserName/Documents/rdflib_python.py
  File "c:\Users\UserName\Documents\rdflib_python.py", line 7
    file_path ="C:\Users\UserName\Documents\jazzmusic.rdf"
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

i already tried adding r infront of my file path and using double slashes in the file path. what do i do?

Use double backslashes OR the r prefix, not both.

i only used r prefix or double backslashes

Please show the exact code you are using and the exact error message(s). We can only try to answer based on the information you provide.

and when i use r prefix or the double backslashes i gt the error
ValueError: exactly one of source, location, file or data must be given

Sorry for making a separate post and not a comment. Could you please try opening the file with utf-8 encoding?
import rdflib

g = rdflib.Graph
filename= r"C:\Users\UserName\Documents\jazzmusic.rdf"
with  open(filename, encoding='utf-8')  as f:
   g.parse(f)


He has not got as far as opening the file yet, so this is not the problem.

Yup, you are right. Reread your comments, they will fix the issue.

also should be g = rdflib.Graph() to create a Graph instance
